# JQuery not processing/selecting from dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1. I have dynamically generated questions with group of radio buttons. I've no problem selecting and processing the static content however. I searched and found out the events needed to be delegated and I used on() method but it's not working.
2. I'm thinking of using onclick method specified in html along with the dynamically generated content. Is it good?

HTML code: The dynamically generated content is appended to the 'question-form'.

```
<section id="questions-form"></section>

<!-- dynamically generated questions with radio options 
<form id="question_0" role="form" class="card">
        <div class="form-group">
            <section>1. Newtons first law of motion gives the concept of</section>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <label class="checkbox" for="option_0_1">
                    <input type="radio" name="q_0" value="a" id="option_0_1">force</label>
                <label class="checkbox" for="option_0_2">
                    <input type="radio" name="q_0" value="b" id="option_0_2">momentum</label>
                <label class="checkbox" for="option_0_3">
                    <input type="radio" name="q_0" value="c" id="option_0_3">work</label>
                <label class="checkbox" for="option_0_4">
                    <input type="radio" name="q_0" value="d" id="option_0_4">inertia</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="mark btn btn-danger">MARK</button>
                <button class="mark btn btn-warning">SKIP</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form id="question_1" role="form" class="card">
        <div class="form-group">
            <section>2. Inertia of body depends on</section>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <label class="checkbox" for="option_1_1">
                    <input type="radio" name="q_1" value="a" id="option_1_1">velocity</label>
                <label class="checkbox" for="option_1_2">
                    <input type="radio" name="q_1" value="b" id="option_1_2">mass</label>
                <label class="checkbox" for="option_1_3">
                    <input type="radio" name="q_1" value="c" id="option_1_3">area</label>
                <label class="checkbox" for="option_1_4">
                    <input type="radio" name="q_1" value="d" id="option_1_4">none of these</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="mark btn btn-danger">MARK</button>
                <button class="mark btn btn-warning">SKIP</button>
            </div>
        </div> 
-->
```

JQuery:

```
$('input:radio').on('click', this, function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("from input radio");
  var question = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
  var selected = $(this).val();
  var msg = question + " " + selected;
  alert(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right way to do it.

Refer jQuery **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:radio', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("from input radio");
  var question = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
  var selected = $(this).val();
  var msg = question + " " + selected;
  alert(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your forms created dynamically to the DOM, the click event will not be available for these radio buttons. In this case, event delegation will help you to attach that event.

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:radio', function (event) {
    // ...
});
```

Use event-delegation to attch events to dynamic elements

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8wKxY/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jquery live() API](http://api.jquery.com/live/) as below:

```
$('input:radio').live('click', this, function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("from input radio");
  var question = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
  var selected = $(this).val();
  var msg = question + " " + selected;
  alert(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Event Delegation : http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/
as  Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:radio', function (event) { //.... });
```